# Are there in-depth theories of parentheses?

Tags: logic, reference-request, semiotics

For example, mustache-emphasized set theories might be styled theories of parenthetical inclusion, extralogical in nature (so something like pairing conjunction with intersection and inclusive disjunction with union, only here "()" goes to "{}"). I also have had a hard time situating erotetic operators in my toy logics, and I noticed that at least in Spanish/adjacent languages, they don't write only, "X?" for some question, but often, "¿X?" Is this an erotetic kind of parenthesis, then, or so **can erotetic functionality (as such) be assimilated to a theory of parentheses?**

I realize this is borderline like asking, "Is there a theory of commas?" or some such thing. Actually, I do know that there are [elaborate theories of quotation marks](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quotation/), though, so maybe the issue isn't reducible to triviality.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: [Parentheses](https://xkcd.com/297/)

Comment: What are "mustache-emphasized set theories?" New one on me. Trying to recall the faces of the usual suspects, Russell, Frege, Zermelo et. al. and none of them had mustaches. Cantor had a 'stache but only as part of a full beard, does that count? His mustache was a proper subset of his facial hair. Zermelo too, 'stache as part of a full beard. Frege too. Is that what you mean? I think men just all had facial hair back in those days.

Comment: Also have you seen the Lisp programming language? Very theoretical and full of parens. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)

Comment: @user4894, I had taken to calling {} "baroque parentheses," but I found out that one of the mainstream names for those are "mustaches." Later, I started calling Yablo sets (infinite sets of sentences that generate Yablo's paradox) "yetis," and I'm dying to find a legitimate analytical reason to take about yetis with mustaches.

Comment: @user4894, thank you for the link! Yes, I definitely need to study the semiotics of programming more. For some reason, on the main math subreddit I think, they have this "controversy" about whether computer science is a kind of mathematics proper or not. Regardless of whether it is, it is still important to consider in this context.

Comment: Oh curly brackets! Well I've coded plenty of those in my time but never heard them called mustache brackets. Great name.  I like the Spanish style of bracketing questions and exclamations so you know what's coming. Another interesting datapoint is the bra-ket notation in quantum physics, which uses unbalanced delimiters <x| and |y> that look terribly wrong. And Python, which has the genius idea of doing away with curly brackets entirely. A long-overdue innovation.

Comment: @user4894, one of the things I've been analyzing is mathematical semiotics. They say that these things called "implementations" can diverge so as to produce "junk theorems," like if Zermelo/pseudo-Peano format is used, then 3 is not an element of 5, but if von Neumann format is used, then 3 **is** an element of 5, and so on. I found a way, maybe, to "code for" an object, a unique ur-element, whose introduction requires that it not be an element of any set besides the set implementing the number 1. So 2 cannot be {u, 1} but must be {1}, and so on. If vN format "kicks in" then maybe 3 is {1, 2}.

Comment: OK, just one last remark (being prompted to transfer this to chat): actually, for now, I have it that 3 = {2} and then vNf kicks in and 4 = {2, 3} = {2, {2}} = {1, {1}, {1, {1}}} even, which is more "poetic"(?). I.e. 4 is the "first ordered pair," so to say, which fits better, I think, than 3 as such. Also, 4 has nice properties that lend itself to being the number as of which vNf kicks in, e.g. 4^2 = 2^4, and this is the only finite example (AFAIK) of this two-valued exponentiation. Infinitywise, like ℵ0^ℵω = ℵω^ ℵ0, then.

Comment: are you looking for a more mathematical or philosophical theory? Because there are quite obviously some basic results on parantheses as used today- ie, that they guarantee an amphibilous parse tree, whether we can determine if a "formula" is actually well formed, etc- we use these for compilers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general term is "bracketing notation" or "brackets".

Brackets are just operators that surround their arguments

```
{2}
[2]
```

rather than proceeding their arguments as prefix operators

```
-x
f(x)
```

following their arguments as a postfix operator

```
5!
```

or going between their arguments as an infix operator

```
a+b
a-b
```

(I once tried to get people to use "outfix" but it didn't take).

For example, curly braces are often used to identify sets, but you could just as well use function notation such as Set(1,2,3) instead of {1,2,3}. In fact some notations do that. Some notations use square brackets to identify lists as in [1,2,3,3,2,1], but they could just as well use List(1,2,3,3,2,1).

In English, double quotes are used to bracket phrases intended as dialog, phrases that are being [sneered at](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Sneer+quotes), or phrases that are mentioned rather than used. This could also be done with function notation as in Quote(Go home!) rather than "Go home!". In Spanish, as you mention, the upside-down question mark is used with the question mark to bracket a question. Again, that could be done with a prefix operator as in "Question(Por qué siempre yo)" rather than "¿Por qué siempre yo?"

Bracket operators (which in a logical world would be called outfix operators) are convenient for things like sets, lists, and quotes where you are usually going to need grouping brackets anyway, so the notation uses an operator that is also a bracket. The case is different with the Spanish upside-down question mark, where I think the purpose is just to warn the reader that a question is coming. That's especially important when reading out loud to an audience. However, there is no reason bracket notation couldn't be used in a formal language for an erotetic marker if it seems convenient.

As an aside, brackets are used for grouping in standard infix notation, such as

```
(a+b)*(c+d),
```

but that usage is not necessary. They aren't needed with Polish notation:

```
*+a b +c d
```

or with the notation of Russel and Whitehead's famous logic trilogy, Principia Mathematica. PM used a notation of dots where more dots separated the expression more:

```
a+b.*.c+d
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This stuff is so fascinating to me. I guess another difference with ¿ and ? is that ¿¿X?? and ¿¿¿X??? and so on, don't seem to add anything besides emphasis to the base, whereas {{X}} represents at least the singleton of the singleton of X. Hmm... I guess I also ought to ask if iterating ¿ and ? actually IS a nontrivial option, for some reason...

Comment: You're welcome. When you write compilers and design programming languages you spend a lot of time looking into stuff like this.

Comment: When you look in to a compiler, the compiler looks back in to you.

Answer (score 3):

[Formal grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) are such a theory. They are covered in any good book on [theory of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_computation), usually in conjunction with [automata theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory). They also serve as the basis of [Chomsky's generative grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_grammar) and their offshoots in modern linguistics.

[*Speech and Language Processing: An Introduction to Natural Language Processing, Computational Linguistics, and Speech Recognition*](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Speech_and_Language_Processing.html?id=fZmj5UNK8AQC&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) by Jufarsky and Martin could serve as a crash course on all these subjects (a rather long one though.)

**Remark:** parentheses do not necessarily have to have similar shape. Thus, a capital latter and a period/exclamation mark/question mark form parenthesis delimiting a sentence  in many languages. This does not work in languages using multiple capitalization (like German) or not using capitalization at all (like Arabic or Hebrew), but a period/exclamation/question mark is still enough to clearly delimit the sentences, so they can be treated as a kind of parentheses.

Comment: Augh, this is why I wonder about being allowed to checkmark multiple answers! Or have a ranked voting system(?) where you vote for your primary choice but it can cycle to other choices (I don't remember exactly how that idea goes/works).

Answer (score 1):

Quotation is an aspect of language and so part of the philosophy of language but according to the linked SEP article, a small part. Far more attention has been lavished upon definite descriptions.

Parentheses in language occur generally to insert incidental or contextual information. For example:

> Mahmoud Darwish who is a Palestinian poet (but now studying in the USSR) happened to run across a friend at the corner cafe he frequented before ...

Generally speaking though, as a matter of style, it's generally frowned upon to have nested parentheses. However, in mathematics, parentheses are everywhere so as to contextualise mathematical expressions. This is especially true for non-associative algebras where to leave out parentheses in an expression would be meaningless.

It's this notion of context which is important in formal grammars where we have context-free grammars and contextful grammars. In fact, according to Wikipedia, no context-free grammar can generate separately well-balanced parentheses, for example:

> {[{]}}

And so contextful grammars are necessary to explore the full syntax of language - but of course not its semantics where Aristotle's theory of change here is fruitful. For instance, the basic structure of sentence is:

> agent (noun) - action (verb) - object (noun)

This is a tripartite classification. Now Aristotle said in his *Physics*, that change occurs when an agent which is potentially capable of change, and can actually cause change, is in contact with an object that can potentially be changed and is actually changed. Now if we lived in a changeless world all we would require  are nouns to name the things of that changeless world. But we do not live in a changeless world but in a changeful world and there we require words that reference the agent, the action and the object. For example:

> The boy kicked the ball

Now returning to the use of parentheses in mathematics, the way we can bracket an expression results in the Stasheff-Tamari polytopes where each vertex represents a particular bracketing of the expression and each edge represents a particular use of the associativity rule. These associahedra are actually important in physics, in particular for the tree-level scattering amplitudes for the "biadjoint cubic scalar theory" where the dual associahedra actually yields the aforementioned amplitide. This was a discovery by Mizeri & Arkani-Hamed in 2017.

Despite all of the above, I expect a philosophy of parentheses per se, as part of the philosophy of language or the philosophy of mathematics is fated to remain a very small fish in a very large ocean.

Comment: I wish I could checkmark this answer too, argh! The concept of associahedra is **definitely** something I need to look in to.

Comment: @Kristian Berry: I would "arrgh" about too much. I'm not after your vote.